# C++ how to use strtok in this case

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to split the following, I need to split it by the function strtok and i wanna obtain the value 1.2597, take note that Down is a dynamic word which can be change. I understand in this case i can use white space as my delimiter, and get the value [1] which is the currency, but how do i go around with it.

CCY   1.2597 Down 0.0021(0.16%) 14:32 SGT   [44]

Comment: what ius the question? you sayed what you need to do....

Comment: strtok will modify the existing string. Are you sure you want to use that?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
char *first = strtok(string, ' ');
char *second = strtok(0, ' ');
```

If you want to convert the number to a `float` or `double` you could also use `sscanf`:

```
char tmp[5];
float number;
sscanf(string, "%s %f", tmp, &number);
```

Or just use `sscanf` on the number token that you got with `strtok`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) to easily and safely achieve this task:

```
// use a regular expression to extract the value
std::string str("CCY 1.2597 Down 0.0021(0.16%) 14:32 SGT [44]");
boost::regex exp("CCY (\\d+\\.\\d+)");
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> match;
boost::regex_search(str, match, exp);
std::string match_str(res[1].first, res[1].second)

// convert the match string to a float
float f = boost::lexical_cast<float>(match_str);
std::cout << f << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

A sequence of calls to this function split str into tokens, which are sequences of contiguous characters separated by any of the characters that are part of delimiters.

Example:

```
char str[] = "now # is the time for all # good men to come to the # aid of their country";
char delims[] = "#";
char *result = NULL;
result = strtok( str, delims );
while( result != NULL ) {
    printf( "result is \"%s\"\n", result );
    result = strtok( NULL, delims );
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
result is "now "
result is " is the time for all "
result is " good men to come to the "
result is " aid of their country"
```